# Are anti-piercing (like a nose ring) rules by employer sueable?

Tags: employment, discrimination, employee

I suppose employers can enforce dress codes, but they also can't obviously discriminate against people who have piercings or tattoos. So, what's the line here? If an employer requests an employee to remove his/her nose ring in order to be offered the job, is that sueable?

Comment: *but they also can't obviously discriminate against people who have piercings or tattoos* Where do you believe such a provision is in the laws? Only very few piercings or tattoos are actually part of protected classes (race, religion, etc.). One of those protected class tattoos would be for example the number on the arm of a holocaust survivor (religion), the taottoos, scarring or piercicngs of many indigene tribes (race & religion)

Answer (score 3):

> ... they also can't obviously discriminate against people who have piercings or tattoos ...

**Why not?**

See [Is an "unmarried with no dependents" employer or higher education requirement discrimination?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/is-an-unmarried-with-no-dependents-employer-or-higher-education-requirement-di/6997#6997)

Discrimination is only illegal where the grounds for discrimination are proscribed. AFAIK "having piercings or tattoos" is not a protected class anywhere in the world.

If the piercings or tattoos are religious or cultural, then discrimination may be illegal, but is they are simply fashion choices then, no.

An employee must follow the lawful and reasonable directions and that may include directions about body area and modification. Reasonable depends on the nature of the job and the workplace. For an example, this is the [policy](https://www.police.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/278815/Body_Art_Modification_Policy_4.0.pdf) of the NSW Police Force; they are presumably well-aware of the law.

Comment: In more civilized parts of the world, employers may only discriminate on the base of things happening during work hours. So putting in a nosering on sundays is *not* something an employer can discriminate against. Having a tattoo on the butt where it is never visible during work hours in the office is *not* somethind an employer is allowed to discriminate against. I'm really at a loss how you can make such sweeping generalizations and get upvotes for them.

Comment: @nvoigt consider that the answer implies "visible."  An employer can't discriminate against an employee with a butt tattoo if the employer doesn't know about it.  But the general statement "may only discriminate on the [basis] of things happening during work hours" is incorrect.  Employers _can_ fire employees for certain activities outside of work, most obviously after the commission of certain crimes.

Comment: @phoog In some juristictions the employer cannot discriminate against it, even if they saw it outside work, for example on the beach at the weekend. In some, they can. I am just surprised that such a sweeping absolute as presented in the answer here can gather upvotes with zero support in actual laws or cases, when there are other specialized answers supported by laws or cases clearly saying this general answer in it's broadness is wrong.

Comment: @nvoigt the general answer is written to refute the OP’s general statement that employer’s can’t discriminate on this basis. The starting point in all jurisdictions is that employers *can* discriminate on any basis and that a law is required to limit this.

Comment: @nvoigt *impacting* work hours: if you are arrested publicly for being involved with the mob, then the bank you work at might fire you for cause anyway.

Comment: In addition to @nvoigtv comment, in some jurisdictions there must be a valid reason. Someone with a visible tattoo may be discriminated against if his position would entail interacting with the public, but not otherwise. I remember reading many years ago some news account a Spanish construction worker whose fitting for to tattoos was considered unjustified by the judges.

Answer (score 3):

**Depends on where you are in the world.**

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), piercings at work may be banned for reasons of employee safety (getting caught in machines, wearing protective equipment), for reasons of hygiene, and *in some cases* for reasons of "professional" appearance. The employer would have to explain why a piercing is problematic, and the employee may challenge that explanation in court. The lawsuit may fail if the explanation is reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

### [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

The analysis is rather simple: the Civil Rights Act of 1964 bans discrimination on the following classes: race, color, national origin, sex, disability, and religion.

Tattoos and piercings, or body art in general, are only rarely an indicator of any of those characteristics:

- Due to history, a number tattooed onto the lower arm will always be connected to [Holocaust Survivors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_survivors) and thus mostly to Jewish people. Discriminating for such a tattoo on an actual survivor would most likely be discrimination based on religion or at least national origin.
- Tribal Polynesian tattoos, including the prominent geometric face tattoos are for many of the indigenous people part of their heritage. Discrimination against a Polynesian person for such a tattoo might be unlawful on the basis of race, nationality **and** religion - often these tattoos have some religious significance.
- Similarly a person might even successfully argue that other traditional body art, such as scarring, is an ingrained part of their race or national origin.

Comment: Would it be legal to discriminate against someone who had a tattoo from a Nazi concentration camp if the person had not been imprisoned there for reasons of "race, color, national origin, sex, disability, [or] religion" but rather for some political reason?

Comment: @phoog that would not be covered under the Civil Rights Act of 1964.

Answer (score 1):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

There is no easy solution here. Two things conflict. One is the right to "free development of personality" which is part of the basic law (some would say constitution) of Germany. This is Article 2 Paragraph 1 of the "Grundgesetz". On the other hand, the employer can regulate how their employees look and what picture the present to the outside, like customers *during work hours*. So for example it is perfectly legal to require a uniform, but also to require a specific style. And then, obviously, there are concerns of safety. Having long hair bundled up so it does not end up in machinery, having short, neat unpainted nails for sports trainers or nurses might even be mandated.

So many times, individual cases have had their day in court, because there is no one simple way to decide. The same requirement in one place of work might be discriminatory, in another perfectly normal, and in yet another even mandated by law.

Some guidelines that normally come into play:

- The employer cannot discriminate based on things the public cannot see. The employers power to order a specific image of their company being transported ends exactly at "image". So for example, a tattoo or piercing that nobody can see during work hours cannot be a reason for discrimination. They *can* on the other hand discriminate by tattoo. A tattoo of bloody skull and crossbones on the forehead with the motto "kill them all" might be appropriate for a pirate themed theme park actor, or a metal band member, but not for a kindergarden nurse.
- The law, mandating basic safety rules, cannot discriminate based on image. If a nosering is considered dangerous for job with physical activity, it does not matter if it is in the form of an evil chainsaw killer, or the form of a happy puppy. It's either dangerous or not.
- If you can hide it during work, be taking it of or hiding it under clothing or any other means, the employer cannot discriminate against you. And if you can remove it or make it less dangerous, for example by wrapping it in tape while you train, safety laws allow this. Discriminating someone because the *have* a tattoo or piercing, even though they take it off/remove it from the public eye/mitigate the danger during work is illegal.

The most iconic and most visible job where these two laws frequently conflict is police. In Germany police cannot have visible tattoos. And while this rule is from a time when only sailors and criminals had tattoos, even when people nowadays sue, it is still a matter of the specific tattoo and whether it is visible. Courts have to decide if a tattoo looks neutral enough for a representative whose job it is to be neutral, and whether or not it is to be considered visible in a police uniform.

The last case I remember was a person with a tiger head as a tattoo on his forearm. Is that visible? I guess, if the uniform officially includes a short sleeved shirt for the summer. Is it non-neutral? I wouldn't know what it stands for, and personally don't care. But to be honest I have no idea which direction that case went, either direction would be possible and not surprising to any German.

Comment: Nitpick: A tattoo of a criminal organisation logo *can* be grounds for dismissal even if invisible, because it is a criminal act in itself.

Comment: @Trish Do you have an example? As far as I know, *having* a tattoo is never a criminal act, only *showing* it can be if it's illegal, for example the infamous Hakenkreuz.

Comment: OLG Hamburg Urt. v. 07.04.2014, Az. 1-31/13 did decide that the logo of the hells angel was illegal federal wide after the organisation was deemed criminal roganisation in some branches, and thus displaying was banned. BSG Urt. v. 28.02.2007, Az. B 3KS 2/07 R deemed that the person performing the tattooing in germany are not protected as art but a person of trade and the act of tattooing is not art in itself. The Tattoo design *might* be art, the tattooed might *become* a piece of art, but until that is reached, displaying such a hells angel tattoo in any way or fashion is illegal.

Comment: Okay, so we agree, that *having* a tattoo is legal, *"displaying"* it (your own quote) is not.

Comment: yes, but there are ways how an arrest for that tattoo can be used to fire you even off premises - e.g. the bank employee arrested for the tattoo when drinking off premises can lose his bank job

Comment: Yes, but they lose their job because of the criminal act of *displaying* the tattoo, not because of *having* the tattoo. They could also lose their job for getting into a bar fight, without any tattoo at all.

Comment: True... I guess the best rephrasing of the initial statement is "A Tattoo, even if usually invisible at work, can be grounds for dismissal if it is displayed in some way and the employer learns from an arrest based on that and the employer learns of that arrest."

Comment: I would rather not follow that line of logic. Feet are not a reason to be fired... unless I am convicted of curb-stomping someone. But that is on my conviction, not on the fact I have feet. I would not want a disclaimer on anyone with feet, that they could be fired because of having feet. Yes, if you use feet to commit a crime, you can get fired. And yes, if you use a tattoo to commit a crime, you can get fired, too. If you just *have* a tattoo, without displaying it, it should be safe, the same way that just *having* feet without using them in a crime is safe.